# Function Javascript for checkbox in a asp:Table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

in my Asp:Table I have a checkbox in each row. I want to reset any control in the row if I check the checkbox. For doing this I set a javascript function at the onclick event in each checkbox.
My problem is to compose the client id for any checkbox (thas is set at checkBox_delega_0 for the first row, checkBox_delega_1 for the second row...)
I try this function

```
function pulisci(riga) {
        var stringa = "checkBox_delega_" + riga;
        if (document.getElementById("<%=" + stringa+ ".ClientID%>").checked == false) {
            document.getElementById("textBox_inizio_" + riga).text = '';
            document.getElementById("textBox_fine_" + riga).text = '';
            document.getElementById("checkBox_documento_" + riga).checked = false;
        }
    }
```

but I have ad error at ".ClientID" part.

Comment: Your trying to mix serverside and clientside code together which will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using <%= tags don't let you "inject" variable names like you are trying.  However, if you are using ASP.NET 4+, you can use the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and set the value to static.  This means that if you call a checkbox "chkMyCheckbox1", when using getElementById, you can reference it as such, and not worry about the value being converted to ctl00?blahblah...  Since it's predictable, you can now work in some logic to determine which controls you want to reference.

Comment: The problem is that I dont'know the number of my CheckBox and I have to create the id by row

Comment: then set their `ClientIDMode` to `Static` and use `document.getElementById(stringa).checked`